# How to find all customization in salesforce org?

Tags: metadata, configuration

I inherited one salesforce org and want to find out all customization in the org including all custom objects, custom fields, workflows, classes, triggers etc to find out the extent of customization. Is there any way to find out all these details?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to find this will be to extract all metadata from the Salesforce org using an IDE .

The extracted source code will have an src file that can indicate the customizations that has happened in the org.

Some IDEs would need package.xml to retrieve source code .You can use package builder open source app linked below to build the package xml

https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com

Alternatively use appexchange apps like config workbook or easy describe .They will help you get Excel sheet with all metadata details.

Comment: Your approach will give all metadata information in the org including standard objects and standard fields and other components.Is there any way to segregate customizations in the extracted code.

Comment: Create an unmanaged package and all the custom components and use the package name to retrieve metadata. Hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull the sources of metadata components using package.xml file.There is an extention in VS Code that allows you to choose components and generate package.xml file using point and click

Salesforce Package.xml generator for VS Code

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VignaeshRamA.sfdx-package-xml-generator

[image]

I am affiliated to this free to use vs code extension as the developer

Comment: Hi Vignaesh, please take an urgent look to [How to not be a spammer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) `Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay.` Though you are disclosing I think you are overdoing. Furthermore if the same answer fits to many questions you might flag possible duplicates instead.